# Additional properties gets included in base class when using automapper in c#

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using .NET Core 3.1 for my Web API project. In that I have below two classes:

**UserDetailDto**

```
public class UserDetailDto
{
    public int UserId { get; internal set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "first name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "last name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

**UserMgmtDto**

```
public class UserMgmtDto : UserDetailDto
{
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public short UserType { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public short Status { get; set; }
}
```

And one entity class:

```
public class UserMgmt
{
    [Key]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string mobile_no { get; set; }
    public short user_type { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_of_birth { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
    public int modified_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime modified_date { get; set; }
    public short status { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my one of the function, I am retrieving records from the database and giving those as response in API.

```
    public async Task<UserDetailDto> GetByIdAsync(int userId)
    {
        UserMgmt user = await _masterRepositories.UserMgmtRepository.GetByKeyAsync(userId);
        UserDetailDto userDetails = _mapper.Map<UserMgmtDto>(user);
        return userDetails;
    }
```

I have created the mapping cfg like below in Profile class:

```
        CreateMap<UserMgmt, UserMgmtDto>();
        CreateMap<UserMgmt, UserDetailDto>();
```

As it can be seen that records are first stored in UserMgmt object and then mapped to UserDetailDto object. I know I haven't done the proper mapping in below line:

```
UserDetailDto userDetails = _mapper.Map<UserMgmtDto>(user);
```

Instead of this, it should be

```
UserDetailDto userDetails = _mapper.Map<UserDetailDto >(user);
```

I have corrected it now, but the output for incorrect mapping was strange. In the object of UserDetailDto, automapper was returning properties of UserMgmtDto.
UserMgmtDto is inheriting UserDetailDto and has some extra properties as compared to UserDetailDto.

In spite of that, UserDetailDto object had all the additional properties of UserMgmtDto like MobileNo, UserType, etc as you can see in the image below:

[image]

In the response as well, I am getting all the properties of UserMgmtDto. I was just wondering that how is it even possible that the class object is getting all the properties which are not even defined in that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserMgmtDto` is a subclass of `UserDetailDto`, it can have more properties and the debugger will display them and the return result will include them. That's how inheritance works.

`userDetails` is an instance of the `UserMgmtDto` class not the `userDetailDto`.

The solution is to not use inheritance in your Dto classes. If you want to map to a Dto with just a few fields then map to *that* Dto.

```
UserDetailDto userDetails = _mapper.Map<UserDetailDto>(user);
```

Comment: Yes. But I can't access any of the UserMgmtDto property like UserType using the userDetails object (e.g. userDetails.UserType), then why is the debugger even showing it and returning it?

Comment: @Sunny You can access those details in code too if you cast it back to a `UserMgmtDto`object. Think of it this way: A lion is still a lion even when you place it in a collection of mammals. If I give you a collection of mammals you can only expect mammalian properties, but if you are given a single mammal you can ask what type of mammal it is, 'cast' it to that type and then examine it as the Lion that it actually is.

Comment: okay. Now I got it. Thanks for explaining this.